# adding string to a select statement to include in result set

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a string to a mysql result set to save manipulating the results with php later.

This is what I want to do but it gives me an error.

```
SELECT 'new' AS condition
    UNION
SELECT p.Name AS title, p.meta_desc AS description, p.product_Id AS id from products AS p
```

I can do this:

```
SELECT p.Name AS title, p.meta_desc AS description, p.product_Id AS id, 'new' from products AS p
```

but it gives new => new , ideally I would like the result column to be called 'descripiton' and retrieve 'condition' => 'new'

Comment: You already have a column called description in your 2nd query. You can't have two columns with the same name. Do you want the string once per row or once per select?

Comment: sorry, I meant 'condition' as in the first query.

Comment: Ah, I see it is the name 'condition' that I can't use for some reason. Changing 'new' AS conditions in the second statement worked. Is there anyway I can use condition as a column?

Comment: Answering my own question: If I put it in quotes - 'new' AS 'condition' works

Comment: Updated my answer, use backticks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.Name AS title, 
       p.meta_desc AS description, 
       p.product_Id AS id, 
       'new' AS `condition`
FROM products AS p
```

You can alias the literal. [Condition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is a reserved word, so you have to use backticks.