# SQL: Append a fix string into selection result set

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using Redshift and is trying to add a certain string into string into selection result set.

I took the link below as reference and tried exactly the same thing, but it did not work.

[adding string to a select statement to include in result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186268/adding-string-to-a-select-statement-to-include-in-result-set)

Would appreciate if anyone could provide a hint.

```
SELECT p.Name AS title, 
       p.meta_desc AS description, 
       p.product_Id AS id, 
       'new' AS `condition`
FROM products AS p
```

***Error message:***

[image]

Comment: what it is showing?

Comment: What is the problem with your current query, which actually looks correct?

Comment: Did you tried `'new' AS condition` or `'new' AS [condition]`... I think that grave (`) is specific to MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in tsql must use ' character instead of ` character

```
SELECT p.Name AS title, 
       p.meta_desc AS description, 
       p.product_Id AS id, 
       'new' AS 'condition'
FROM products AS p
```

or without ' character

```
SELECT p.Name AS title, 
       p.meta_desc AS description, 
       p.product_Id AS id, 
       'new' AS condition
FROM products AS p
```

Comment: I've tried but not worked. It works when nothing is used , neither (`) or (') for the column name..

Answer (score 1):

I deleted (`) for the column name then it works....

Answer (score 1):

In Redshift column names are quoted by double quotes (").  It may be that *condition* is a reserved word and needs quotes.

```
SELECT p.Name AS title, 
       p.meta_desc AS description, 
       p.product_Id AS id, 
       'new' AS "condition"
FROM products AS p
```

Please post the error message if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thx for the comment. I made mistake. After deleting (`) from the column name, it works.